# Foco permanente em um campo - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Tenho uma aplicação com vários campos, mas gostaria de deixar o foco apenas em um específico e não possibilitar a retirada do mesmo em nenhuma situação.
Forcar o foco sempre neste campo, e se o usuário tentar retirar, ele bloqueia e não permite essa ação.
Possível essa tarefa?
Trabalho com um campo TextEdit do DevExpress, semelhante ao TextBox.

Abraço!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilizando a função `PreviewLostKeyBoardFocus` do TextEdit.

```
private void textNome_PreviewLostKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NewFocus != null && !LayoutHelper.IsChildElementEx((DependencyObject)sender, (DependencyObject)e.NewFocus))
    {
        textNome.Focus();
        Keyboard.Focus(textNome);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar o evento `LostFocus` do TextBox.

```
private void textBox1_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.ActiveControl = textBox1;
}
```

Note que usei o nome `textBox1` somente como exemplo.

Comment: Eu trabalho com uma UserControl, não tenho esse ActiveControl. Tentei também textBox1.Focus(), mas ele entra em um loop infinito.

Comment: Consegui uma outra solução... Irei colocá-la

Comment: Boa, espero ter ajudado.